ESP32 HTTP Requests Fail When Connected to Jio Air Fiber via Netis Router
I was trying to connect my ESP32 with Jio Air Fiber, but I encountered an issue because the 2.4GHz and 5GHz Wi-Fi channels cannot have separate SSIDs in this router, so the ESP32 could not connect to the Wi-Fi.
To solve this, I connected a netis router to the Air Fiber Router using Ethernet as a LAN-to-LAN connection, and then connected the ESP32 to the netis router using 2.4GHz Wi-Fi.
Now, when I make an HTTP request from the ESP32, it returns a -1 HTTP code. However, when I connect the ESP32 to an Android phone's hotspot, the HTTP requests work fine.
Notes: I have both GET and POST requests, and both returns -1. When I connect my phone with the netis router, I can serf the web fine. I did no additional coding, I have used the default wifi and http client lib comes with platform io esp32 dev kit.
Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

HTTPClient client;


for example i have made a GET request to https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Kolkata.  I think it has to do something with my router setup which I'm unaware of. My router is in access point mode.

I solved this issue by setting the router to access point mode and disabling dhcp server mode. these settings were not available in the netis router so i had to use a tp-link router.

I'm facing the same issue with the ESP32-WROOM-32E.
From what I understand, the Jio AirFiber router supports 2.4GHz and 5GHz bands. However, the ESP32 still can't connect to the 2.4GHz band. Is that correct?
The problem might be because the ESP32 supports 802.11b/g/n modes, whereas Jio AirFiber provide 802.11ax. You may need to contact Jio customer support and request that the 2.4GHz band be configured to support 802.11b/g/n on your router.

Even though Jio AirFiber has both 2.4GHz & 5GHz, the SSID & password remains same for both bands, and they can't be separated with the current firmware setting.

I encountered the same issue with multiple Wi-Fi connections, including Jio Air Fiber. The problem was linked to the use of a Queue task in the setup, causing errors related to shared memory allocation. Once I removed the Queue task from the setup, the HTTP requests worked properly. It's important to note that the issue was not specific to any particular Wi-Fi network, but rather related to task memory allocation.

In my case it was due to access point's setting, once i disabled dhcp server mode on the sub router (tp-link) it started to get 200/302 responses after a while.
